# Yahoo.com - Certificate from untrusted issuer

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, osx-el-capitan

If I try to reach flickr.com or yahoo.com, I get the message that the certificate is issued by an untrusted issuer and the CSS is not loaded. See screenshot:

[image]

Is that an issue on my end or does yahoo has some problems? I tried different browsers and I have this problem for more than a day now. I am running Mac OS X El Capitan...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox "Untrusted Connection" warnings when visiting reputable HTTPS sites when using child's account](http://superuser.com/questions/853659/firefox-untrusted-connection-warnings-when-visiting-reputable-https-sites-when)

Comment: @Reaces Not a duplicate. That question is for Windows not OS X

Comment: @DavidPostill Regardless of the platform, both seem to be a case of a trusted certificate missing from the machine, as the Verisign class 3 is missing in his screenshot, which should be installed by default as [documented by apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205204). And the solution is the same as it is for windowns, import the missing certificates. As such I disagree, this is a duplicate (as both cause and answer are the same).

Comment: @Reaces Yes, maybe it is then.

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry for the wall of text, I was trying to explain my reasoning, and reading it again I might have gone a bit overboard :)

Comment: @Reaces No need to apologise. It is always good to fully explain your point ;)

Comment: @Reaces Also possible dup of Security SE question [Why is Symantec/Verisign CA appearing as an invalid authority?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/85830)

Answer (score 1):

#### Is that an issue on my end or does yahoo have some problems?

It doesn't appear to be a Yahoo issue.

It is possibly an issue with your account's keychain.

See Security SE question [Why is Symantec/Verisign CA appearing as an invalid authority?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/85830) for a possible explanation/solution.

On Windows 7 with Firefox 41.0.1 I get a validate certificate:

[image]